# git tag -l is not showing any result

Tags: git, gitlab, tags, gitlab-ci, cicd

for few projects git tag -l is not showing any output, However for some projects it returns tags on gitlab pipeline.
locally on my machine it works for all projects, only not working on gitlab for few projects.

```
        tag = None
        tag = subprocess.check_output(
                            ["git", "tag", "-l"]) \
                            .decode("utf-8").rstrip("\n")
        if not tag:
            version = default_version
```

It is taking default version

I tried creating new tag for the project on gitlab, then It works,
for older tags its not working

Comment: If `git tag` does not list tags, that just means you have no tags. Remember that GitLab's CI system makes clones; these clones have *their own* branch and tag names that may or may not match any other clone's branch and/or tag names. CI systems often make *shallow* clones on purpose, and sometimes omit *all* branch and tag names also on purpose. In these cases you must override the CI system's defaults, either with CI configuration, or with explicit `git fetch` operations and/or Git-level configurations.

Answer (score 1):

With [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#discover-commits-by-their-tag-in-commits-list-view) (March 2023), you can quickly confirm if a project does have tags or not:

> ### Discover commits by their tag in commits list view
>
> Identifying commits that have been tagged just got simpler.
> View the commits list at **`Repository > Commits`** to see commits with their tags attached.
> This view helps you understand what commits have been added since a tagged release commit.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_10/Commits-list-view-with-tags.png -- Discover commits by their tag in commits list view]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/tags/index.html#view-tagged-commits-in-the-commits-list) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18795).

That way, you can understand why your `gitlab-ci` pipeline does not get any tag for some project.